# How to generate fingerprint for Android MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, keystore

For my final year project i am making an android application (Mobile based tracking for personel optimization). Application is heavily dependent on tracking of user for this purpose i need google maps to be appeared on emulator. So, to generate the finger print i need to give the path of file debug.keystore through command prompt but the problem is that i dont know where this file debug.keystore is actually located in my system. I will appreciate your views if you have any idea to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, you can see this by going to the Window menu and selecting "Preferences" then expand the Android tab and select "Build". There it will show you the path to your debug keystore.

It defaults to

```
HOME_DIR/.android/debug.keystore
```